# How can I close apps properly/shutdown the system via ssh?

Tags: macos, applications, ssh, shutdown

I need to know if there's a proper way to close apps via ssh and if it's posible shut down the system without the `sudo halt` or `sudo init 0` (because I think those ways are not good for the system when there are apps running)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to start by saying that there is nothing wrong with using `halt` or `shutdown` from the command line.

In fact if you issue either of those commands then any running applications will get exactly the same message from the system as if you chose "Shut Down..." in the Finder.

The advantage of using `sudo shutdown` is that you can shutdown the system regardless of which users are logged in.

Comment: If I exec `halt` or `shutdown` the running apps will appear when I log in next time :/

Answer (score 3):

To close apps, use

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Mail\" to quit"
```

<sup>Replace `Mail` with the name of the application you want to quit.</sup>

To shutdown correctly, use

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to shut down"
```

Comment: I guess i can have aliases of that in my `.profile`, right?

Comment: @naoxink Indeed

Comment: If you are going to use `osascript` in a shell script or the command line then you have to be incredibly careful with quote characters and spaces. The first version of this answer had them all wrong. Also, this method will only work if the user logged on to the Mac and the ssh user are the same **and** there are no other users logged on.

Comment: I suppose it will be something like this: `alias myHalt='osascript -e "tell application \'Finder\' to shut down"'`. Am I right? Anyway it seems to be more issues with this method than `halt` option :/